# Obfuscating a GWT webapplication with ProGuard

Tags: java, gwt, obfuscation, vaadin, proguard

I am trying to obfuscate my GWT (Vaadin) application using Proguard. Ive never obfuscated java code before and this is my first attempt using Proguard.

I have my config file set as follows:

```
-libraryjars JAVA_HOME\rt.jar
-libraryjars MYPATH\test\WebContent\WEB-INF\lib\appfoundation.jar
-libraryjars MYPATH\test\WebContent\WEB-INF\lib\blackboard-2.1.1.jar
-libraryjars MYPATH\test\WebContent\WEB-INF\lib\cssinject-0.9.jar
-libraryjars MYPATH\test\WebContent\WEB-INF\lib\eclipselink.jar
-libraryjars MYPATH\test\WebContent\WEB-INF\lib\eclipselink-jpa-modelgen_2.0.2.v20100323-r6872.jar
-libraryjars MYPATH\test\WebContent\WEB-INF\lib\gwt-visualization.jar
-libraryjars MYPATH\test\WebContent\WEB-INF\lib\iText-5.0.4.jar
-libraryjars MYPATH\test\WebContent\WEB-INF\lib\javax.persistence_1.0.0.jar
-libraryjars MYPATH\test\WebContent\WEB-INF\lib\javax.persistence_2.0.0.v201002051058.jar
-libraryjars MYPATH\test\WebContent\WEB-INF\lib\vaadin-6.4.4.jar
-libraryjars MYPATH\test\WebContent\WEB-INF\lib\vaadin-calendar-0.5.1.jar
-libraryjars MYPATH\test\WebContent\WEB-INF\lib\vaadin-chameleon-theme-1.0.1.jar
-libraryjars MYPATH\test\WebContent\WEB-INF\lib\VisualizationsForVaadin.jar
-libraryjars "C:\Program Files\eclipse\configuration\com.vaadin.integration.eclipse\download\gwt-dev\2.0.3\gwt-dev.jar"
-libraryjars "C:\Program Files\eclipse\configuration\com.vaadin.integration.eclipse\download\gwt-user\2.0.3\gwt-user.jar"
-injars   test.war
-outjar   test_after.war
-printseeds
-ignorewarnings
-keep public class TestApplication extends com.vaadin.Application {
public void init();
}
```

I then execute using the proguard command:

```
java -jar proguard.jar @test.pro
```

I dont get any errors with the configuration file but i do receive lots of warnings. The output file is created but im concerned about the warnings. Do i need to specify further jar files in my config file? I have listed all the jars that i am using in my application. Is there anything else i am doing wrong?

Below is a snipped of the last 20~ lines of the command line output

Thanks in advance

S.

```
      Maybe this is library method 'sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcStatement { java.sql.Connection getConnection(); }'
      Maybe this is library method 'sun.jdbc.odbc.ee.CommonDataSource { java.sql.Connection getConnection(); }'
      Maybe this is library method 'sun.jdbc.odbc.ee.ConnectionPoolDataSource {java.sql.Connection getConnection(); }'
      Maybe this is library method 'sun.jdbc.odbc.ee.DataSource { java.sql.Connection getConnection(); }'
      Maybe this is library method 'sun.jdbc.odbc.ee.PooledConnection { java.sql.Connection getConnection(); }'
      Maybe this is library method 'sun.rmi.transport.StreamRemoteCall { sun.rmi.transport.Connection getConnection(); }'
Note: org.eclipse.persistence.sdo.helper.DynamicClassWriter accesses a declared method 'writeReplace()' dynamically
      Maybe this is program method 'org.eclipse.persistence.sdo.SDODataObject {java.lang.Object writeReplace(); }'
      Maybe this is program method 'org.eclipse.persistence.sdo.helper.ListWrapper { java.lang.Object writeReplace(); }'
      Maybe this is library method 'com.sun.corba.se.impl.presentation.rmi.InvocationHandlerFactoryImpl$CustomCompositeInvocationHandlerImpl { 
Note: there were 4 unresolved dynamic references to classes or interfaces.
      You should check if you need to specify additional program jars.
Note: there were 10 accesses to class members by means of introspection.
      You should consider explicitly keeping the mentioned class members
      (using '-keep' or '-keepclassmembers').
Warning: there were 3649 unresolved references to classes or interfaces.
         You may need to specify additional library jars (using '-libraryjars').

Warning: there were 173 unresolved references to program class members.
         Your input classes appear to be inconsistent.
         You may need to recompile them and try again.
         Alternatively, you may have to specify the option
         '-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclassmembers'.
```

Comment: The part of your application that gets sent to the browser isn't java anymore, it's plain old javascript (this is the core idea of GWT). Depending on your GWT settings, it is already very obfuscated (although GWT's main goal with this is minification). Unless you're worried about someone with access to your server reading the class files, there is little point in obfuscating the java part.

Comment: I wont be hosting the code on my server it will be given to a client. Id prefer to obfuscate the code. The output file does not include my code. It has all the library jars but my actual code is not there in the output file. It did create a jar file for my code but it only has a css file in there - no java code :(

Comment: Any ideas as to why my java code is not being included in the proguard output file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GWT generates code in two parts.

1. Client side code. This is what runs in your browser and consists of the user interface plus any async calls to the server. While you write Java source it is transformed from the source straight into Javascript. i.e. the GWT compiler doesn't even look at the class files. To obfuscate the generated JS, use the GWT compiler flags (see below)
2. Server side code. The server code would be the end points your client app calls. e.g. you might invoke GWT RPC calls and have GWT servlets as end point. Obfuscate your web app like you would any other - trial and error through Proguard or similar. Start off with a simple configuration that lightly obfuscates and then proceed from there.

As the GWT client side is generated from Java source code there is no easy way to obfuscate before feeding to GWT. I suppose you could somehow obfuscate through Proguard and then decompile that and feed it to the GWT compiler. It seems like overkill but it may be possible.

The normal way to obfuscate is to specify `-style OBF` to the GWT compiler. This will thoroughly obfuscate your code. You could probably go further and run it through another JS obfuscator though the law of diminishing returns, bugs etc. applies.

I suggest you understand what gets generated when you supply OBF as the style. It's probably quite sufficient for your purposes. Obviously the more stuff you put on the server side (e.g. security, cookie validation etc.) the less it matters what code is in the client.

Comment: thanks locka, I compile my project via eclipse. Can you give any pointers as to how i can specify -style OBF to the GWT compiler? Thanks

Comment: I use GWT with maven so I don't know exactly what GWT integrated with Eclipse does. This doc suggests you can change the setting from the GWT compile button - http://code.google.com/eclipse/docs/gwt_compile.html. Change the setting and then inspect the resulting .htm output to see if its obfuscated.